# I have a view that runs fine when executed, but when I try to open it in design mode, it throws a parsing error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, sql-view

I don't have enough reputation to post a screen capture, so I'll do my best to explain what's happening.

As I said in the title, it is a view that executes just fine when you run it normally. When I try to open it using design view, it throws this error:

> i - The following errors were encountered while parsing the contents of the  > SQL pane:
>
> Error in WHERE clause near '('.  Unable to parse query text.

There is nothing wrong with the WHERE clause, or my syntax considering it runs fine. My concern is that there are extended properties that attempt to define how it will look in design mode. I am completely unfamiliar with this concept.

Is this a bug, or a problem with my SQL?  I have changed the names of the tables for security reasons

```
WHERE     (dbo.tblxx.bolObsolete = 'False') AND (dbo.tblxy.bolObsolete = 'False')
```

Comment: post your SQL Statement!!! We cannot read minds....

Comment: I posted my WHERE clause, where it is saying I messed up

Comment: I cannot figure out how to post the whole query formatting wise, but I can assure you there isn't a syntax error.  It has something to do with the way the designer is parsing the query and I was wondering if somebody else has ran into this problem.

Comment: What happens if your right click on the view and press Script View As > ALTER To > New Window? Does it script the view? I suggest you try to stop using the designer as it has many limitations.

Comment: I can script the view as create, alter, drop and create, etc. The designer is the only problem.  I could care less about the designer, but my PDL likes using it and he wants to be able to pull up the designer without getting an error message.

Comment: For anybody reading this, I did some research and found that the designer has trouble bringing in BIT data types, and my views have bit types in them.  For now, I'm thinking this is the issue.  This bug was not fixed until 2012 as far as I'm concerned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no solution to the problem except using T-SQL in management studio. This is a bug, or as Microsoft calls it by design.

The view designer has more issues then just BIt datatypes. There are several valid SQL syntaxes that are not supported by designer. That's the reason I never use the designer but just write my create/alter statements in management studio.

Comment: I'm marking this as an answer because it does explain what is going on. This is close to what I told my project lead a while back after doing some research.

Comment: Maybe I should have rephrased my answer:"There is no solution to the problem except using T-SQL in management studio. This is a bug, or as Microsoft calls it by design" Hopefully this will stop the discussion on answer or not. Another comment here is that apparently you need a reputation before being able to answer questions. Well I don't have a reputation on Stackoverflow. But I do have over 15 years of experience on SQL Server and am part of the local SQL community. @SQL Taylor: Thanks!! If you ever have a question let me know. I will try to help you! As a community should!!

Comment: Thanks @Nicoverbaenen ! I really appreciate the time you took out of your day to give your input. I totally agree, sometimes the stack overflow community can be very critical, and in this case, the unfortunate answer is that there isn't really an answer other than to use TSQL in Management studio.